# Handle HTTP cookies to simulate browser like behaviour

Tags: http, cookies, jmeter

There is a site which accepts logins from the same user until browser is restarted. I try to simulate this in `JMeter` with `HTTP Cookie Manager`. I defined cookies, use those in all the logins, but seemly it doesn't use those. After successful login site enables only the same user to login until browser is closed, but I can login with other users too in same `JMeter` test execution. I use standard `Cookie Policy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define cookies manually, JMeter's cookie manager manages cookies **automatically**

As per the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager):

> The Cookie Manager element has two functions:
>   First, **it stores and sends cookies just like a web browser**. If you have an HTTP Request and the response contains a cookie, the Cookie Manager automatically stores that cookie and will use it for all future requests to that particular web site. Each JMeter thread has its own "cookie storage area". So, if you are testing a web site that uses a cookie for storing session information, each JMeter thread will have its own session. Note that such cookies do not appear on the Cookie Manager display, but they can be seen using the View Results Tree Listener.

If you need to mimic "Logout" you can tick `Clear Cookies each Iteration` box and each [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) loop (iteration) will simulate "clean" login.

See [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) - A Guide for more information on HTTP Cookie Manager use and troubleshooting.

Comment: What is the reason of `User-defined cookies` field in Jmeter in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the web site is not using cookies at all for the purpose of tracking logins, and instead uses "browser session storage". (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)  And it is possible that the cookies that you see are added by other parties / sources, for example google analytics etc.

Comment: It uses cookies, I chekced in browser's dev tools, I see exact cookies and its values too. I tried to disable cookie storage/usage in browser and I see right behaviour.